# Overlay PNGs with ImageMagick while keeping transparency

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two images:

**Image 1**

In this image, the white region plus the white + pink region are transparent.

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

**GOAL**

I want to merge both images (Image 1 in front, Image 2 behind) by:

1. Keeping the transparent region from Image 1 so that Image 2 can be
   seen through the white mask.
2. Having the chance to locate Image 2 by vertically centering the photo in the middle of the white region.

Then, I'd like to obtain a result like this:

[image]

**HOWEVER**

I am using the following command in ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31 in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
convert \( Image1.png -resize 447x640 \) \( -compose Overlay Image2.png \) -gravity north -composite Image3.png
```

I've tried countless times but the best result I can get (by using command above) is **Image 3**. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

**Image 3**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want using Imagemagick in Unix syntax:

Img:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

```
convert \( mask.png -alpha off \) img.jpg \( mask.png -alpha extract -negate \) -compose over -composite result.png
```

or more simply:

```
convert mask.png img.jpg -compose dstover -composite result.png
```

[image]